# Batch file REG QUERY command searches in 32 bit registry instead of 64 bit

Tags: batch-file, registry, inno-setup, 32bit-64bit

In my batch file, I am doing a simple command to get the VirtualBox install path.

```
REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle\VirtualBox /v InstallDir
```

It works wonders when I execute the batch file from the command line, but no value is given if I launch that same batch file from Inno Setup.

After a long while of testing, I noticed it was searching in the 32 bit section of the registry only when the batch file was launched from Inno Setup.

To test that theory, I looked at a 32 bit Registry located there:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\NuGet\Repository
```

In my batch file, I enter the following command (notice that I don't specify the Wow6432Node, which should be wrong)

```
REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\NuGet\Repository\
```

Indeed, when running the batch file from the command line, it does not find the registry key. However, when that same batch file is launched from Inno Setup, it finds \NuGet\repository just fine.

The question now is. How do I get the 64 bit registry key (Virtual Box) with my batch file so that it works from both the command line and Inno Setup?

Comment: First thing is that you don't need to run a batch file to get a registry value. Inno Setup has direct support functions for this. But anyway, what makes you confused is the [`registry redirector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx) and the fact that you were running a 64-bit command prompt and a 32-bit Inno Setup installer. Your batch file executed from a 64-bit command prompt looked into the 64-bit registry node, whilst when running from 32-bit Inno Setup into the 32-bit registry node. To get what you ask, you'd have to run a 32-bit command prompt.

Comment: I know I can get a registry key from Inno Setup, but I had a requirement to get has much logic as possible out of Inno Setup, to place it in a batch file, in order to make that operation available in command line. Your explanation made the issue much clearer to me, thank you for that. However, if I understood correctly, Wow6432Node is where the 32 bit keys are stored, right? If so, Virutal Box is in the 64 part. Is there a way to access 64 bit keys from a 32 bit environment?

Comment: That requirement is a straight way to hell! But well, I've helped many suicidal requirements, so why not that yours :-) How do you run that batch file in Inno Setup and which bitness of the command prompt do you want to support ? For Inno Setup there can be an easy solution e.g. by specifying a path to the `reg.exe` of a bitness that you prefer as a working directory for your execution function (or script entry). But I'm not sure if it's the best way since I'm not a fan of batch scripting nor command prompt.

Comment: I call my batch file that way: Exec('cmd',  '/C ' + ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '\Batch.bat ' + dest_path, '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ReturnCode);

Comment: Ideally, I would want to support all bitness. 32 cmd to 32 bit Virtual  box (or 64bit to 64 bit) works fine. I can support easily 64 bit cmd to 32 bit Virtual box (check in Wow6432Node if not found the first time). The issue is with the 32 bit cmd and 64 bit Virtual box. If there is no way to get the registry key that way, I guess I can to do search for the file VBoxManage.exe in the C: drive.

Comment: You cannot run that single line batch file for 32-bit as well as for 64-bit `cmd.exe`. You'd need to extend your batch script somehow. Currently, one of them would fail. That's because each of them calls different `reg.exe` depending on their bitness. Just like your executed 64-bit command line and 32-bit Inno Setup did (either one of them failed depending on which node you queried).

Comment: I feared so. I even tried calling the different 'reg.exe' manually in the batch file and it did not accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing since I did not have any more time to put on it. It works for all cases, except when a Virtual Box 64 bit is installed in a folder that is not the default one and that the batch file is called in a 32 bit environment.

```
set vb_path=""

for /f "tokens=1-2*" %%A in ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle\VirtualBox" /v InstallDir') do (
  set vb_path="%%C\VBoxManage.exe"
)

IF %vb_path%=="" (
  REM Virtual Box not found. Search in 32 bit virtual box from 64 bit cmd
  for /f "tokens=1-2*" %%A in ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Oracle\VirtualBox" /v InstallDir') do (
    set vb_path="%%C\VBoxManage.exe"
  )
)

IF %vb_path%=="" (
  REM Still not found. Must be 32 bit env. with 64 bit Virtual Box
  REM Search in default installation folders.
  IF EXIST "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" (
    set vb_path="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe"
  ) ELSE (
    IF EXIST "%ProgramW6432%\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" (
      set vb_path="%ProgramW6432%\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe"
    )
  )
)

IF %vb_path%=="" (
  ECHO VirtualBox folder not found in registry or default installation path!
  EXIT /b 1
)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can call something like

```
REG QUERY HKLM\SOFTWARE /reg:32
```

or

```
REG QUERY HKLM\SOFTWARE /reg:64
```

to explicit target the registry for 32bit or 64bit.

This is not mentioned when calling `REG /?`, but I found it here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/948698/you-cannot-use-the-reg-exe-utility-to-access-64-bit-registry-keys-on-a 
I am using this on Windows 7 Pro 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

If I wanna know using batch files, Windows version x86 or x64, I use simple script (not tested at Inno Setup)

```
@echo off
rem DISCOVERY WINDOWS VERSION x86 or x64

reg query HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0 | find /i "x86" > nul 2>&1
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto x64

rem DISPLAY OS NAME AND VERSION 

:x86
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
SET CURRENTKEY=HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,*" %%A IN ('reg query "%CURRENTKEY%" 2^>NUL^|FIND /I "ProductName"') DO ECHO                       %%B 32 Bits found...
echo.
ping -n 5 localhost >nul 
cls
goto systemx86

:x64  
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
SET CURRENTKEY=HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,*" %%A IN ('reg query "%CURRENTKEY%" 2^>NUL^|FIND /I "ProductName"') DO ECHO                       %%B 64 Bits found...
echo.
ping -n 5 localhost >nul 
cls
goto systemx64

rem YOUR SCRIPTS BELOW

:systemx86
echo Start your commands for x86! by Iremar Domingos
pause

:systemx64
echo Start your commands for x64! by Iremar Domingos
pause
```